# CSS Selector compare 2 attributes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way to build a selector that would match where two attributes have the same value, but can't find a syntax. Is this possible? How?

What I hoped would work:

```
[data-valueA=data-valueB]
```

When I know valueA and valueB ahead of time, I could do:

```
[data-valueA="knownValueForA"][data-valueB="knownValueForB"] {}
```

But I don't know the values and aren't concerned with them in this case, just knowing when they are the same.

Here's a fiddle to explore with: https://jsfiddle.net/rainabba/m49e4e7k/

To clarify, I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: this is a javascript job :) CSS is only about styling :(

Comment: As it stands, the answer to your question is "no". CSS cannot apply styles in cases where multiple selectors happen to have matching values.

Comment: @GCyrillus: Why would that be a limitation here? You have attribute selectors that match individual attributes against specific values, so this doesn't seem that far off...

Comment: @BoltClock **values are unknown** and then need to be compared to another value before to apply some style . CSS is not about programming as far as i know :) . If possible values stand in a certain range, maybe a preprocessor like sass could create every possible selector ....

Comment: @gcyrillus "CSS is not about programming" No, it's about using patterns to select elements then apply styles to them and it's ever evolving. A few years ago, someone would have told me I couldn't do math in CSS too, but now.... https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation. I don't think comparing values is "programming" any more than any other operation in CSS which must parse every element, checking values for some condition. This would be a pretty simple operation compared to much of what is possible now since the comparison is only on a single element.

Comment: @rainabba CSS works with selector , yes i know about pattern, but , the point here is that the pattern, to search for, is unknown and should be compared ... how CSS can read HTML to find that unknown chain of caracters ?

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible with standard CSS.

Although you hadn't exactly asked "Well in that case, what *can* I do?", leaving this answer on its own feels completely insufficient, so here's also a jQuery solution for something that might do the trick.

Assuming you are looking for `div`s only, the code below will work. Otherwise, you can edit the selector in the first line of the jQuery to be something other than `$("div")`

```js
    $("[data-valueA]").each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var firstAttr = $this.data("valuea");
        var secondAttr = $this.data("valueb");
        if (firstAttr == secondAttr) $this.addClass("redBackground");
    });
```

```css
  div {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .redBackground {
      background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-valueA="MyValue" data-valueB="MyValue">
    ValueA and ValueB match
</div>

<div data-valueA="XXX" data-valueB="YYY">
    ValueA and ValueB do not match
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Nice.

Comment: Have to vote down because this requires JS and jQuery. I believe my question is clearly qualified to CSS.

Comment: You asked for something that is literally impossible in CSS, and you're going to vote my answer down because I told you "This isn't possible, but here's the next best thing." and wrote you a custom jQuery function?

Comment: @Santi Not trying to be a jerk, but the question is tagged "css" and "css-selectors" and is asked pretty clearly. Your answer doesn't address the question; "CSS Selector compare 2 attributes". If I was asking for a solution in general, I'd gladly have upvoted it as it would be a good answer (though I wouldn't ask that since it's pretty simple and likely has been asked many times). I can't even find another question addressing this though so I think it's a good question and deserves an appropriate answer. Notice that despite that, my question hasn't even been upvoted once :/

Comment: Your question hasn't been upvoted because it *isn't possible*. Questions get upvoted for being helpful to other users, but a question with no answer is of no help to anyone. You had multiple users, many of which very prominent (50k rep+)  answer you, as did I - The answer to your question is **it isn't possible in CSS**. I went the extra mile and offered you working alternative, which a 50k user corroborated in the comments. If you want to punish users who go the extra mile to offer you a solution, then go for it, but good luck getting anyone to help you in the future.

Comment: **"Your answer doesn't address the question"... Here is your question:** *I'm looking for a way to build a selector that would match where two attributes have the same value, but can't find a syntax. Is this possible?* **Here is the first line of my answer:** *This is not possible with standard CSS.*

Comment: It's fine. My point is simple: You asked whether or not something was possible, and my answer could've simply been "No.", and it seems as though you would've been perfectly fine with that. It's only because I went above and beyond and actually gave you a simple alternative that *does* work, that you wanted to downvote my answer. And trust me, I believe if any other prominent SO user saw your logic here, they would be equally unhappy. You asked a "trap" question with no answer - and then downvoted anyone who answered it.

Answer (score 2):

Not much useful, but if you know the attribute values won't exceed a certain length, and the possible set of characters is limited, you can programmatically generate all the possibilities.

For example, with characters `abc` and a maximum length of 4,

```css
[data-valueA=""][data-valueB=""],
[data-valueA="a"][data-valueB="a"],
[data-valueA="aa"][data-valueB="aa"],
[data-valueA="aaa"][data-valueB="aaa"],
[data-valueA="aaaa"][data-valueB="aaaa"],
[data-valueA="aaab"][data-valueB="aaab"],
[data-valueA="aaac"][data-valueB="aaac"],
[data-valueA="aab"][data-valueB="aab"],
[data-valueA="aaba"][data-valueB="aaba"],
[data-valueA="aabb"][data-valueB="aabb"],
[data-valueA="aabc"][data-valueB="aabc"],
[data-valueA="aac"][data-valueB="aac"],
[data-valueA="aaca"][data-valueB="aaca"],
[data-valueA="aacb"][data-valueB="aacb"],
[data-valueA="aacc"][data-valueB="aacc"],
[data-valueA="ab"][data-valueB="ab"],
[data-valueA="aba"][data-valueB="aba"],
[data-valueA="abaa"][data-valueB="abaa"],
[data-valueA="abab"][data-valueB="abab"],
[data-valueA="abac"][data-valueB="abac"],
[data-valueA="abb"][data-valueB="abb"],
[data-valueA="abba"][data-valueB="abba"],
[data-valueA="abbb"][data-valueB="abbb"],
[data-valueA="abbc"][data-valueB="abbc"],
[data-valueA="abc"][data-valueB="abc"],
[data-valueA="abca"][data-valueB="abca"],
[data-valueA="abcb"][data-valueB="abcb"],
[data-valueA="abcc"][data-valueB="abcc"],
[data-valueA="ac"][data-valueB="ac"],
[data-valueA="aca"][data-valueB="aca"],
[data-valueA="acaa"][data-valueB="acaa"],
[data-valueA="acab"][data-valueB="acab"],
[data-valueA="acac"][data-valueB="acac"],
[data-valueA="acb"][data-valueB="acb"],
[data-valueA="acba"][data-valueB="acba"],
[data-valueA="acbb"][data-valueB="acbb"],
[data-valueA="acbc"][data-valueB="acbc"],
[data-valueA="acc"][data-valueB="acc"],
[data-valueA="acca"][data-valueB="acca"],
[data-valueA="accb"][data-valueB="accb"],
[data-valueA="accc"][data-valueB="accc"],
[data-valueA="b"][data-valueB="b"],
[data-valueA="ba"][data-valueB="ba"],
[data-valueA="baa"][data-valueB="baa"],
[data-valueA="baaa"][data-valueB="baaa"],
[data-valueA="baab"][data-valueB="baab"],
[data-valueA="baac"][data-valueB="baac"],
[data-valueA="bab"][data-valueB="bab"],
[data-valueA="baba"][data-valueB="baba"],
[data-valueA="babb"][data-valueB="babb"],
[data-valueA="babc"][data-valueB="babc"],
[data-valueA="bac"][data-valueB="bac"],
[data-valueA="baca"][data-valueB="baca"],
[data-valueA="bacb"][data-valueB="bacb"],
[data-valueA="bacc"][data-valueB="bacc"],
[data-valueA="bb"][data-valueB="bb"],
[data-valueA="bba"][data-valueB="bba"],
[data-valueA="bbaa"][data-valueB="bbaa"],
[data-valueA="bbab"][data-valueB="bbab"],
[data-valueA="bbac"][data-valueB="bbac"],
[data-valueA="bbb"][data-valueB="bbb"],
[data-valueA="bbba"][data-valueB="bbba"],
[data-valueA="bbbb"][data-valueB="bbbb"],
[data-valueA="bbbc"][data-valueB="bbbc"],
[data-valueA="bbc"][data-valueB="bbc"],
[data-valueA="bbca"][data-valueB="bbca"],
[data-valueA="bbcb"][data-valueB="bbcb"],
[data-valueA="bbcc"][data-valueB="bbcc"],
[data-valueA="bc"][data-valueB="bc"],
[data-valueA="bca"][data-valueB="bca"],
[data-valueA="bcaa"][data-valueB="bcaa"],
[data-valueA="bcab"][data-valueB="bcab"],
[data-valueA="bcac"][data-valueB="bcac"],
[data-valueA="bcb"][data-valueB="bcb"],
[data-valueA="bcba"][data-valueB="bcba"],
[data-valueA="bcbb"][data-valueB="bcbb"],
[data-valueA="bcbc"][data-valueB="bcbc"],
[data-valueA="bcc"][data-valueB="bcc"],
[data-valueA="bcca"][data-valueB="bcca"],
[data-valueA="bccb"][data-valueB="bccb"],
[data-valueA="bccc"][data-valueB="bccc"],
[data-valueA="c"][data-valueB="c"],
[data-valueA="ca"][data-valueB="ca"],
[data-valueA="caa"][data-valueB="caa"],
[data-valueA="caaa"][data-valueB="caaa"],
[data-valueA="caab"][data-valueB="caab"],
[data-valueA="caac"][data-valueB="caac"],
[data-valueA="cab"][data-valueB="cab"],
[data-valueA="caba"][data-valueB="caba"],
[data-valueA="cabb"][data-valueB="cabb"],
[data-valueA="cabc"][data-valueB="cabc"],
[data-valueA="cac"][data-valueB="cac"],
[data-valueA="caca"][data-valueB="caca"],
[data-valueA="cacb"][data-valueB="cacb"],
[data-valueA="cacc"][data-valueB="cacc"],
[data-valueA="cb"][data-valueB="cb"],
[data-valueA="cba"][data-valueB="cba"],
[data-valueA="cbaa"][data-valueB="cbaa"],
[data-valueA="cbab"][data-valueB="cbab"],
[data-valueA="cbac"][data-valueB="cbac"],
[data-valueA="cbb"][data-valueB="cbb"],
[data-valueA="cbba"][data-valueB="cbba"],
[data-valueA="cbbb"][data-valueB="cbbb"],
[data-valueA="cbbc"][data-valueB="cbbc"],
[data-valueA="cbc"][data-valueB="cbc"],
[data-valueA="cbca"][data-valueB="cbca"],
[data-valueA="cbcb"][data-valueB="cbcb"],
[data-valueA="cbcc"][data-valueB="cbcc"],
[data-valueA="cc"][data-valueB="cc"],
[data-valueA="cca"][data-valueB="cca"],
[data-valueA="ccaa"][data-valueB="ccaa"],
[data-valueA="ccab"][data-valueB="ccab"],
[data-valueA="ccac"][data-valueB="ccac"],
[data-valueA="ccb"][data-valueB="ccb"],
[data-valueA="ccba"][data-valueB="ccba"],
[data-valueA="ccbb"][data-valueB="ccbb"],
[data-valueA="ccbc"][data-valueB="ccbc"],
[data-valueA="ccc"][data-valueB="ccc"],
[data-valueA="ccca"][data-valueB="ccca"],
[data-valueA="cccb"][data-valueB="cccb"],
[data-valueA="cccc"][data-valueB="cccc"]
```

I generated that with this code:

```js
function generateString(chars, maxLen) {
  var current = new Array(maxLen);
  return function* main(pos) {
    yield current.join('');
    if (pos == maxLen) return;
    for (let ch of chars) {
      current[pos] = ch;
      yield* main(pos+1);
    }
    current[pos] = '';
  }(0);
}
for (let value of generateString("abc", 4)) {
  value = CSS.escape(value);
  document.write('[data-valueA="'+value+'"][data-valueB="'+value+'"],<br />');
}
```

Of course, this becomes too absurdly huge to be useful in practice. If you want to allow the 26 latin letters in lowercase and uppercase, the 10 digits, and 2 additional symbols, that's 64 possible characters. With a maximum length of 10, there are these many possibilities:

```
64^0 + 64^1 + ... + 64^10 = 1.171221845949812801 * 10^18
```